# Terminology: do variables and symbols have a value or are they bound to a value?

Tags: common-lisp

The arguments of a function, I mean the *x* and the *y* as in

```
(defun my-function (x y ) body)
```

are sometimes also called the *local variables* or the *local parameters* or the *formal parameters* or even the *parameters*.  Are all these terminologies really correct in Lisp?  Is another terminology more suited?

Furthermore one says that the arguments of a functions are bound to the values of the arguments of the function that is calling.  Is this terminology "*bound to*" correct?  Or do we have to say that they will "*have the value*" of the arguments of the function called?

And does one say that a global symbol is "*bound to a value*" or "*has the value*"?  I read in a book that this is a  cause of enormous confusion.  In that book it is suggested that the words "*bound to*" should not be used for global symbols, but should only be used for the arguments of a function.  But on the other hand, the build in function *boundp* like in

```
(boundp 'x))
```

is used in Lisp also for global symbols.  This would suggest that symbols do not "*have a value*" but are "*bound to a value*"?

Comment: these two variants are more or less synonym in the Lisp world

Answer (score 7):

**Common Lisp** uses this terminology:

A function has a defined list of *parameters*.

Evaluation of a function call adds a *binding* of each *parameter* with the corresponding *value* from the *arguments* to the current lexical environment.

*Global variables* have a *binding* in the *global environment*.

**Reference**

See [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm) (a HTML variant of the *ANSI Common Lisp* standard), and there the chapters on Evaluation/Compilation and the Glossary. That document describes the *terminology*, useful for Common Lisp. Other Lisp dialects (Emacs Lisp, ISLisp, Visual Lisp, ...) may have different terminology.

**Example**

```
(defun foo (a b)
  (bar a b a b))
```

Above function explained in the comments:

```
(defun foo        ; <- the name of the global function is foo

           (a b)  ; <- the list of parameters of the function foo

                  ; <- in the body, a and b are bound

                  ; in the body there is one function call form
  (bar            ; <- the function bar gets called
       a b a b)   ; <- the arguments to be evaluated
  )
```

Comment: It is Robert Wilensky who in his book "common LISPcraft" urged for clarification about the terminology "binding".  In mathematical logic, the parameters of the function are bound to the values of the arguments.  But Wilensky seems to insist that global variables "have" values and are not "bound" to values.  I guess that he is right in insisting for clarity here.  The reason for asking is that there does not seem a rigid terminology in the Lisp community.  Even in printed texts, different authors agree to disagree.   The suggestion done here is reasonable.

Comment: @user3144191: That book "Common LISPcraft" was years written before the ANSI Common Lisp standard was published. The ANSI Common Lisp standard now provides the terminology for that language.